# Guide for migrating from Swiper 4.5.0 to 6.8.1 or latest?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, swiper.js, ngx-swiper-wrapper

I'm trying to find the steps how to upgrade Swiper 4.5.0 (nicely used even now with Angular 12 project) to 6.8.1, or to a newest Swiper and there are several question about possible upgrade:

For Swiper 6.8.1, do I still need ngx-swiper-wrapper?

https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-swiper-wrapper/blob/master/README.md  states:
Version 10.0.0 will be last release of this library since this is now obsolete due to latest Swiper including direct support for Angular.

I can't find what is the oldest Swiper version that fully supports Angular 12 and if "ngx-swiper-wrapper" needs to be removed for Swiper 6.8.1 https://swiperjs.com/changelog#6-8-1-2021-08-03 .

Or, the best way is to completely remove both swiper 4.5.0 + ngx-swiper-wrapper, and setup
Swiper 8.4.6 (2023-01-17) from scratch without any wrappers for Angular 12 project?

P.S. The look on pages should remain unchanged and stay as a current look (I hope it's possible with default settings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way was to:

```
Or, the best way is to completely remove both swiper 4.5.0 + ngx-swiper-wrapper, and setup Swiper 8.4.6 (2023-01-17) from scratch without any wrappers.
```

It took a while to rewrite everything though.